# Web api parse FromQuery parameter name

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have strict API routing requirements. This must be a Get request and the routing cannot be changed. The user can search for people by name, but he can also search for them by part of the name:

**api/People?name=Tom** - "Tom" can be in any part of the name, ignore case

**api/People?name:contains=Tom** -  "Tom" must be at the beginning of the name, ignore case

**api/People?name:exact=Tom** - "Tom" must be case sensitive

How it should be implemented in the controller?

There is an option with 3 parameters, can this be improved?

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(
        [FromQuery(Name = "name")] string name, 
        [FromQuery(Name = "name:contains")] string beginName, 
        [FromQuery(Name = "name:exact")] string exactName)
```

Comment: May I suggest "public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]FormDataCollection formbody)". Check out this link for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this must be a get request and the solution is not suitable for me. I corrected the description

Comment: I will use two parameters like `name` and `operator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom model binding,here is a demo:
NameModel:

```
public class NameModel {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string beginName { get; set; }
        public string exactName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [Route("/GetByName")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName([ModelBinder(typeof(NameBinder))]NameModel nameModel)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

NameBinder:

```
 public class NameBinder:IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            var model1 = new NameModel();
            var name=bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("name").FirstValue;
            var beginName = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("name:contains").FirstValue;
            var exactName = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("name:exact").FirstValue;
            if (name.ToLower().Contains("tom")) {
                model1.name = name;
            }
            if (beginName.ToLower().StartsWith("tom")) {
                model1.beginName = beginName;
            }
            if (exactName.Contains("Tom")) {
                model1.exactName = exactName;
            }
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model1);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]